# How can I make a process I start during an SSH session run after the session has ended?

Tags: ssh, process, centos, webserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection)

I have a process which is basically a web-server, I start it during an SSH session. However, when I leave the session (by closing the PuTTY windows), it stops running and responding to requests. This is true even if I end the command with a `&`. With Apache, I don't have this problem, it comes with a stop, a start, and a restart script. I'd like to create something like that for this program.

How can I start a process, so that it will continue running even after I end the SSH session I started it in?
Also how can I set it to restart itself if it stops for some reason?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection). Also near-dupes: [How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it) [Running continuous jobs remotely.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/running-continuous-jobs-remotely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start it in a `screen` session.

```
screen
```

Now start the process:

```
myprocess
```

Then, detach the screen session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>.

You can reattach to the screen session again by typing:

```
screen -r
```

If you have more sessions running you can list them with:

```
screen -ls
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a daemon (fork it twice or have it started by the system's `init` daemon) or for temporary stuff use `screen`.

Comment: How do I do that?